# erratic behaviour of setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

Here instead of one by one execution, this code only executes for last value. That is for the 1 to xObj.length-1 co-ordinates, it goes inside the loop function and goes outside the loop function and it doesn't executes the loop code. But, for the last co-ordinates it executes the code perfectly. I can't figure out why?

xObj and y Obj are **arrays**  of the form **[1,2,3,4...]** and contains co-ordinates to be plotted.

I am trying to get the output so that, points gets plotted one by one and fades out.. i.e. one points get plotted and then it fades out then another point gets plotted then it fades out.

This is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
    console.log("for loop running " + i);
    x = xObj[i];
    y = yObj[i];
    var centerX = x
    var centerY = y
    var radius = 10;

    var alpha = 1, /// current alpha value
        delta = 0.002; /// delta = speed
    flag = 0;
    loop();

    function loop() {

        console.log("inside loop" + centerX + centerY);
        alpha -= delta;
        if (alpha <= 0) {
            console.log("heya_amigoes");
            flag = 1;
            return;
        }
        console.log("hi1");
        /// clear canvas, set alpha and re-draw image
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
        ctx2.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx2.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx2.fill();
        ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx2.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx2.stroke();

        console.log("hi2");
        //requestAnimationFrame(loop); // or use setTimeout(loop, 16) in older browsers
        setTimeout(loop, 16)
        console.log("hi3");
    }

    console.log("outside loop func");

}
```

sample of what console is printing initially for the rest of the co-ordinates except the last one.

```
for loop running 0
hello.php:129 inside loop10393
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:155 outside loop func
hello.php:105 for loop running 1
hello.php:129 inside loop52410
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:155 outside loop func
hello.php:105 for loop running 2
hello.php:129 inside loop394525
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:155 outside loop func
```

For the last co-ordinate:

```
inside loop10357
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
```

and at last this is getting printed at last don't know why?

```
inside loop10357
hello.php:137 hi1
hello.php:149 hi2
hello.php:152 hi3
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
hello.php:129 inside loop10357
hello.php:133 heya_amigoes
```

Comment: because once the for loop is done, `centerX`, for example, will be the last value of centerX for all instances of the "loop" ... you need a closure

Comment: simplest solution - `for (i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // the body of your current for loop goes here //
    }(i));
}`

Comment: `if(xObj.length !== i)setTimeout('loop', 16);` I would have an argument on that `loop` function, and don't define it in a loop. Super sloppy.

Comment: @JaromandaX current for loop? but the loop is a function.. and should i put everything inside the function(i)?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {` - that's your current for loop - anything between `for (i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {` and the final `}` is **the body of your current for loop** - I made no use of the word "function" when referring to the loop

Comment: @JaromandaX Did what you told.. now all points are being shown but the problem is I want the points to be shown one by one but now what's happening is it keeps showing the points with different alpha value i think.. 
it shows points one by one very fast then again it shows and then again until it disappears..
Thanks for helping

Comment: what is missing from your question is what you expect as the "output" - so it's hard to give you an all encompassing answer

Comment: @JaromandaX added expected output in question.